# FARMReader is timeout

Tags: bert-language-model, haystack

It get stuck in FARMReader for long (30+ mins) and time out. Any reason?

```
reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path="deepset/roberta-base-squad2",use_gpu=True)

retriever = ElasticsearchRetriever(document_store= document_store)
 
pipe = ExtractiveQAPipeline(reader, retriever)

# predict n answers
prediction = pipe.run(query=question, top_k_retriever=10, top_k_reader=3)`
```

I try to run it local on pycharm & farm-haystack==1.15.1 & elasticsearch-8.7.0

Comment: Some tips and considerations: 1) Currently Haystack does not support Elasticsearch 8 2) Why don't you install the latest version of Haystack, 1.17.2? 3) Do you have any GPU?

Comment: Also, please run the following tutorial in Colab: https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/03_scalable_qa_system and see if it works